# How to use Redux Saga with AWS Amplify?

Tags: null, this, redux-saga, aws-amplify

I'm trying to make an API call using AWS Amplify's helper methods with Redux Saga.

```js
import { API, graphqlOperation } from 'aws-amplify';
import * as R from 'ramda';
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';

import { listQuestions } from '../graphql/queries';
import { openSnackbar } from '../snackbar/snackbar-reducer';
import { addQuestions, fetchQuestions as fq } from './question-reducer';

const toAction = R.pipe(
  R.path(['data', 'listQuestions', 'items']),
  addQuestions
);

function* fetchQuestions() {
  try {
    const result = yield call(
      API.graphql,
      graphqlOperation(listQuestions, { limit: 100 })
    );
    yield put(toAction(result));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    yield put(openSnackbar(e.message));
  }
}
```

As you can see, I'm using the `API.graphql` and `graphqlOperation` helper methods from the JS framework part of AWS Amplify.

But, this always throws the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_graphql' of null
    at APIClass.graphql (API.js:831)
```

The given code at `APIClass.graphql` looks like this:

```js
APIClass.prototype.graphql = function (_a) {
    var paramQuery = _a.query, _b = _a.variables, variables = _b === void 0 ? {} : _b, authMode = _a.authMode;
    var query = typeof paramQuery === 'string' ? parser_1.parse(paramQuery) : parser_1.parse(printer_1.print(paramQuery));
    var _c = query.definitions.filter(function (def) { return def.kind === 'OperationDefinition'; })[0], operationDef = _c === void 0 ? {} : _c;
    var operationType = operationDef.operation;
    switch (operationType) {
        case 'query':
        case 'mutation':
            return this._graphql({ query: query, variables: variables, authMode: authMode });
        case 'subscription':
            return this._graphqlSubscribe({ query: query, variables: variables, authMode: authMode });
    }
    throw new Error("invalid operation type: " + operationType);
};
```

Why would `this` be `null` here? Is there a way to use the GraphQL helper methods from AWS Amplify with Redux Saga?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found the solution. You need to supply a `this` [context](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#callcontext-fn-args) to `call`.

```js
yield call([API, 'graphql'], graphqlOperation(listQuestions, { limit: 100 }))
```

Comment: Thank you. But why this is necessary to make graphql requests works?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I made SignIt work with this lines:

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
const response = yield call([Auth, 'signIn'],{ username, password });
```

Just replace the method and parameters you need, 'signUp' for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
async function apiCall(data: any) {    // put action what you need
      return await Auth.signUp(data);
    }

function* signUp({ signUpData}) {
  try {
    const response = yield apiCall(signUpData); // and call it

    yield put({
      type: ACTION.AUTH.SIGN_UP.SUCCESS,
      data: response,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({ type: ACTION.AUTH.SIGN_UP.FAILURE, error });
  }
}
```